# Android how to sum the same object an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hello guys maybe my doubt is simple but could not solve.
My question is as follows:
I have an ArrayList of objects, these objects have number, name and value.
I would like to sum the values of these objects when the number and name are the same.
I thought of creating a new ArrayList to go the added values sum but to no avail.

My class:

```
    private class ItemAdubacao {
    float quantidadeProduto;
    String produto;
    int tanque_id;

    public float getQuantidadeProduto() {
        return quantidadeProduto;
    }

    public void setQuantidadeProduto(float quantidadeProduto) {
        this.quantidadeProduto = quantidadeProduto;
    }

    public String getProduto() {
        return produto;
    }

    public void setProduto(String produto) {
        this.produto = produto;
    }


    public int getTanque_id() {
        return tanque_id;
    }

    public void setTanque_id(int tanque_id) {
        this.tanque_id = tanque_id;
    }

}
```

I'm adding objects of this class in an ArrayList. 
What I want is to go through this ArrayList checking objects that have Tanque_id and produto equal to sum the quantidadeProduto.
As I said I thought I'd create a new ArrayList and go adding the objects already added. For example:

```
    public void finalizar() {
    Adubacao adubacao = new Adubacao();
    adubacaoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ItemAdubacao itemAdubacao : itemAdubacaoArrayList) {
        if () {

        }

    }
    adubacaoArrayList.add(adubacao);
}
```

But do not know how to IF

Comment: create variable sum, with value 0, and iterate trough arryalist and add elememnt to sum

Comment: [Short, self contained, correct, example](http://sscce.org) Please explain your problem in details, including your object types and examples, and samples of your data.

Comment: Show your code. Explain the specific problem. @DavidCesarino Other way around... brackets go around text, parenthesis around link :)

Comment: @tnw It doesn't matter how much I do it (I edited 3 times), I _always_ get it wrong! :)

Comment: The question is not about Android neither about java. You ask about simple data structures and simple algorithms to process this structures. I think the accurate reading about topics above will solve your problem.

Comment: @TNW, Hello guys, sorry for the English, tried to make the question a little clearer, if you can help me appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @RaphaelMM It's absolutely crucial that you learn how to help yourself when you run in to issues like `do not know how to IF`. Please just Google something like `java if statement`. This turns up numerous tutorials about how to write an if statement. It really sounds like you need to pick up an introductory java tutorial/book as this extremely common and basic construct is covered by virtually any one you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question, is not simple question IF
first added boolean equals in my class

```
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ItemAdubacao adubacao = (ItemAdubacao) o;
        if (this.getTanque_id() == adubacao.getTanque_id() && (this.getProduto().equals(adubacao.getProduto()))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

then I created an ArrayList to separate the duplicate objects and adding the sum of values

```
     public void finalizar() {
    ArrayList<ItemAdubacao> itensIguaisArrayList;
    itensIguaisArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    adubacaoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ItemAdubacao itemAdubacao : itemAdubacaoArrayList) {
        if (!itensIguaisArrayList.contains(itemAdubacao)) {
            itensIguaisArrayList.add(itemAdubacao);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < itensIguaisArrayList.size(); i++) {
        float soma = 0;
        for (ItemAdubacao linha : itemAdubacaoArrayList) {
            if (linha.equals(itensIguaisArrayList.get(i))) {
                soma += linha.getQuantidadeProduto();
            }
        }
        itensIguaisArrayList.get(i).setQuantidadeProduto(soma);
    }
}
```